# Run Mojave apps on High Sierra

Tags: applications, catalina, high-sierra, mojave, stocks.app

Is there any way to run new Mojave apps (like Voice Memos, News, Stocks) in High Sierra?

I tried to modify info.plist in particular with stocks, but the app gives me an error, I suppose because some missing files. But, is there any way to run this app on High Sierra?
Here you can see the error in stock when I open the program (for no Italians: "borsa" means stock):

Dyld Error Message:

```
  Library not loaded: /System/iOSSupport/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NewsArticles.framework/Versions/A/NewsArticles
  Referenced from: /Volumes/VOLUME/Borsa copia.app/Contents/MacOS/Stocks
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are new Apps only compatible with the latest version(s) of Mac OS X & not backward comatible with earlier versions of the Operating System?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72538/why-are-new-apps-only-compatible-with-the-latest-versions-of-mac-os-x-not-ba)

Answer (score 3):

No, these new apps are built using iOS-based frameworks that only exist on Mojave. These frameworks are located within `/System/iOSSupport` which is why you're seeing that error message, as that directory (and the files within it) do not appear in previous versions of macOS.

Answer (score 2):

No way

There will be differences in the system APIs between different operating systems.

Plus there will be new functions in the new OS which have no equivalent in older ones